# CSS modal won't sit on top

Tags: html, css, canvas, modal-dialog

I've created working CSS modals using [this](http://gamingjs.com/ice/) online editor, with buttons overlaid on top of a THREE.js canvas.

I recently downloaded Brackets on my desktop mac, and most everything has gone well even though I'm not good with that kind of stuff, but now I'm trying to do pretty much the same thing from Brackets. It doesn't sit on top! It just pushes the THREE.js canvas down. I've tried a few ways to fix this, but none seem to be doing anything. Might I be using the editor incorrectly?

I'll be using the modal for an in-game pause menu, so I'll use the same techniques for a small opaque pause button in the corner.

Here is my CSS:

```
#modal {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#modal_content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="modal">
  <div id="modal_content">
    <p>Stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd prefer to keep the modal to just HTML, CSS, and Javascript, but if there is a simple way to achieve this goal with another language, please let me know.

Any and all help will be very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. This seems like a completely appropriate way to achieve the modal. With the opacity at 0 it was hard to see it working, and this answer really wont fix your actual issue, but hopefully this snippet shows that the issue is elsewhere. Can you add more of the html and css code that illustrates the problem?

```css
#modal {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#modal_content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  font-size: 50px;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <div id="modal_content">
    <p>Stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>

<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! After the confirmation that the code was fine, I was able to test a few things, and the problem is that my stylesheet wasn't linked to my html page correctly. So I'll just need to figure out how to do that. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  You may want to remove this question then since it most likely won't be helpful to the community and sometimes these questions get on a downvote train. No prob to wait and see.